# Weird wrapping issue with answer titles in profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed while browsing [Alex's profile](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/31/alex-angas) that something is weird with the way the answer title and votes are wrapping.

[image: Wrapping fail]

It looks fine on my profile though:
[image: Wrappin' like a boss]

Bug?

Edit: This is also happening on [David Lozzi's profile](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/286/david-lozzi). Fine in IE 8. Broken in Firefox 7.0.1.

Maybe bump `.answer-link` width down to 770 from 800:

```
.answer-link {
    color: #555555;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 770px;
}
```

Comment: Note to self: re-check this after the new profile design hits SP.SE

Comment: @Shog9 Looks like this is no longer an issue with the new profile design.

Comment: Excellent, I was hoping that'd happen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed with the introduction of the new profile design. Wahoo!